How to view HEIC pictures on a web page in a browser?
While format support has largely been solved in general by FFmpeg, VLC, libmpv and the like, things are moving in the direction of web browsers being used as a first port of call by developers of frontends. I'm using the Immich photo server currently, whose desktop client just runs in a browser. With my many HEIC photos from a recent iPhone, I can't view them natively, and so currently must re-encode them at the expense of server storage into formats of inferior resolution and high size for non-local users, among other trade-offs.
My question is, in the sense that a program like Jellyfin can develop a web-based client with libmpv to make it widely codec-compatible, surely it should be possible to just download an extension or similar that lets a browser decode HEIC, or other popular codecs and formats? I'm looking for something that will make a browser (Windows Chrome/Firefox/Edge/other) decode HEIC payloads in <img> tags and have them appear as normal images.

Apparently, at this time, there is no browser that displays HEIC images. That said, if one has installed the codecs in the operating system to handle HEIC (and HEIF), there are JavaScript libraries being developed that one could try to add that capability to an existing browser.
This seems very much a do-it-yourself project, though. It's easy to download one of these files and display in VLC, IrfanView, Paint.NET, etc., but not to show in a browser.
BTW, Firefox, and likely other browsers, have support for AVIF, another new video format.

It is also very crucial to point out that HEIC is a proprietary format and in order to make it work on Windows, you need to buy the codec, which is something many people are not willing to do, and without this, it will never work. It is therefor a much better idea to move away from the HEIC format or limit yourself to Apple users, which is still a minority.

I have the codec installed from Microsoft Store, yeah. I'm looking for a procedure to get a browser to display a web app like Immich with HEIC working. Safari does support HEIC but I'm constrained by Windows.

I am looking into a userscript that loads libheif but don't really know what I'm doing.

@LPChip, there are some free sources for the codecs: https://www.majorgeeks.com/content/page/hevc_heic.html Hopefully, those still work.

@Pyoro, this appears to be the bleeding edge of software -- still in development -- so don't expect to find a finished answer. Your best bet, other than converting files, is to view them in VLC or similar app.

@DrMoishePippik That link, I found 4 months ago when one of our customers wanted to get support for the HEVC codec, that solution no longer works, and redirects you to the codec you have to buy.

You can probably find a different "codecs from the device manufacturer" free download somewhere on Microsoft Store. I've not needed to check for a bit. I remember it being a sanctioned option for those whose OEMs purchased the codec license.
And yeah I get that it's experimental; I just wanted to check if there was a known solution. I'll ask on StackOverflow, thanks.

@LPChip One can install “HEIF Image Extensions” from Microsoft Store for free.

@Betty no you cannot. Try it. It will redirect you to a different item that you must buy for 0.99. I tried because I needed it.
